# select records form tableA and tableB where tableA.id = tableB.id, records from tableA once

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working in Codeigniter. I have two tables in MySql database "menus" and "menus_child". 
The structure is:

> table: menus

id | menu_name 
1  | products

> table: menus_child

child_id | id | child_name 
1                 | 1  | product1 
2                 | 1  | product2 
3                 | 1  | product3 

What I want to achieve is, Select the "id, menu_name" from "menus" and also with it Select "child_name" from "menus_child" Where menus.id = menus_child.id. Remeber its "id" as in table "menus" and not "child_id" as in table "menus_child" 
Here is what I am doing:

```
$this->db->select('menu_name');    
      $this->db->from('menus');
      $this->db->select('child_name');
      $this->db->from('menus_child');
      $this->db->where('menus.id = menus_child.id');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $data = $query->result();
      return $data;
```

However, this query returns

```
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [menu_name] => products
                [child_name] => product1
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [menu_name] => products
                [child_name] => product2
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [menu_name] => products
                [child_name] => product3
            )
```

But  I want it to be something like this:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [menu_name] => products
                [child_name] => product1
                [child_name] => product2
                [child_name] => product3
            )
```

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql=$this->db->query(
"SELECT * from menus ");
$data=$sql->result_array();
foreach($data as $key=>$mainmenu){
$data[$key]['child']=$this->getChild($mainmenu['id']);
}
return $data;

function getChild($menu_id){
   $sql=$this->db->query(
    "SELECT * from menus_child where id='$menu_id'");
 $data=$sql->result_array();
return $data;
}
```

Comment: A minor correction though. In the foreach loop "mainmenu" should be "$mainmenu"